# Can I stop Mac while FileVault is Decrypting?

Tags: macos, filevault

As I asked above, I am leaving work and I have to bring my computer home.

Can I close the screen and resume it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. FileVault encryption / decryption pauses when on battery power, at shutdown, and at sleep. It will continue when you plug it in and log in.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204837

Comment: Here's documentation from Apple's Support site that verifies this answer: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204837